# SQL IF Statement to Insert Into the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to query a data set that is stored in two different SQL schemas depending on how we receive the data. I have created the two queries to look at dataset 1 and dataset 2 and it formats that data into two separate temp tables (in the same format).

I'm now trying to do the second step which is working out which temp table has been populated putting this data into a new temp table in order to move on to step 3.

To do this, I'm trying to create an IF statement to work out which dataset we receive but can't seem to get the query to work (even though I have seen solutions from other people's similar queries).

This is my code:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#Final_Prem') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #Final_Prem 
END

DECLARE @Command varchar(500)

DECLARE @DS1 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @DS2 AS FLOAT

SET @DS1 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Dataset1 )
SET @DS2 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Dataset2 )

IF (@DS1 IS NULL OR @DS1 = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO #Final_Prem FROM #Dataset2'
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO #Final_Prem FROM #Dataset1'
END

EXECUTE (@Command)

SELECT * FROM #Final_Prem
```

The error I keep getting is

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 18
>   Invalid object name '#Final_Prem'

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: `#Dataset1` & `#Dataset2` isn't a table.

Comment: Instead of `SET @DS1 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Dataset1 )` use `SELECT @DS1 = SUM(PREM) FROM #Dataset1`

Comment: Hi JNevill, when I remove the brackets and SELECT I get the Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. error?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use single-hash tables in dynamic queries. The session that runs the dynamic query is different than the outside one, and thus has no access to it.

If you are sure you will be running the proc/query once each time, you can change the # table to a ##table.

If you want to use both dynamic sql and concurrent runnings, you can save @@SPID into a variable and use it on the end of the ## table names.

Comment: I think you mean "single-**h**ash" table?

Answer (score 0):

The query *as a whole* needs to compile before any of it can run, and it looks like the last line `SELECT * FROM #Final_Prem` is causing compilation to fail because the `#Final_Prem` table does not (yet) exist at that stage.

If you are using SSMS, then you can fix it by putting a line containing only `GO` after the EXECUTE statement. `GO` is a pseudo statement (not part of the SQL language) that chops the input into batches( pieces), which are compiled and run one by one, thus preventing such compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're having a scope issue.

A temporary table is only visible to the session where it's created. Your table `#Final_Prem` is created within the scope of the `EXECUTE (@Command)` statement, which, unfortunately, is it's own session, and is different from the scope of the calling procedure. As soon as that `EXECUTE()` is done, the temp table is dropped.

You have two options.

1. Create a real table.
2. Use a global temporary table (`##Final_Prem` instead of
   `#Final_Prem`).

Either way, the table will be accessible from both the inner and outer sessions.

*Edit (response to comment):* Code in comments is pretty hard to read, so here's what the code would look like using a global temp table:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..##Final_Prem') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE ##Final_Prem END

DECLARE @Command varchar(500)

DECLARE @DS1 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @DS2 AS FLOAT

SET @DS1 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM ##Dataset1 )
SET @DS2 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM ##Dataset2 )

IF (@DS1 IS NULL OR @DS1 = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO ##Final_Prem FROM ##Dataset2'
END ELSE BEGIN3
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO ##Final_Prem FROM ##Dataset1'
END

EXECUTE (@Command)

SELECT * FROM ##Final_Prem
```

I also changed the two `Dataset` tables to globals, because they're both accessed from both sessions, too. So you'd need to change them elsewhere, since they're not defined within this code block.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your help. I have amended my query to look like this with the ## on the second argument. I was just wondering if I'm following your advice correctly?            
 BEGIN
 SELECT * INTO #Final_Prem FROM #DS2
END ELSE BEGIN
 SELECT * INTO ##Final_Prem FROM #DS1 
END

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place the select statement inside the dynamic SQL too like below:

```
IF (@DS1 IS NULL OR @DS1 = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO #Final_Prem FROM #Dataset2 SELECT * FROM #Final_Prem'
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO #Final_Prem FROM #Dataset1 SELECT * FROM #Final_Prem'
END

EXECUTE (@Command)
```

Please check the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8643ca374ba68b71aae99fd55c0661e6).

Comment: But the two `#Dataset` tables aren't going to be available from inside the dynamic statement.